# Consuming a REST API using Angular Observable

Tags: angular, rest

I recently created a rest API using flask , now when I tried to use it with my Angular web App , I am receiving these errors ( I Tried to follow the same steps mentioned in the official docs : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 )

```
getBills(): void {
          this.BillService.getBills()
             .subscribe(bills => this.billData=bills);
      }
       }
```

the error is :

> > ERROR in ../src/app/Bills/add-new-bill.component.ts (61,31): Type '{} | BillModel[]' is not assignable to type 'BillModel[]'.  Type '{}
> >     | BillModel[]' is not assignable to type 'BillModel[]'.   Type '{}' is
> >     not assignable to type 'BillModel[]'.
> >         Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.

this is my bill.service code :

```
getBills() {
    return this.http.get<BillModel[]>('http://localhost:5000/bills/123')
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError('getBills'))
        );
}
```

and this is the model Class for my bill object :

```
export class BillModel {
    Amount: number;
    Bill_id: number;
    CreatedAt: string;
    From: string;
    PaymentDate: string;
    PaymentStatus: boolean;
    To: string;
};
```

and it works perfectly 
but I want to work with the observable mechanism so would u please help or explain to me why I am getting that kind of error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the second argument to the `this.handleError` method.

```
getBills() {
    return this.http.get<BillModel[]>('http://localhost:5000/bills/123')
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError('getBills', []))
        );
}
```

If you do not pass the second argument to the error handler and the http observable throws, your `catchError` operator will return observable of `undefined`.

```
private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
    return of(result as T);
  };
}
```

So right now the return type of your `getBills()` method is actually `BillModel[] | undefined`. And you cannot assign that to the `bills` property.

Comment: thanks now it works I still have one problem :
I want the getBills method to return an array of Bills but it doesn't 
in console I receive an undefined